# TypeScript - can not see interface from class' object defition

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I'm having strange issue:

```
interface PreferencesData {

}  
class Background {        
    a:PreferencesData;         // OK
    private state = {
        preferences : PreferencesData   // NOT OK
    }
..
```

When "NOT_OK" - it just can not see `PreferencesData` and refuses to compile.

But for "a" it is visible and no complaining.

Do I miss something?

**UPDATE:** if I change `interface` to `class`, then it is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the type information in a type annotation *prior* to the object, like this:

```
class Example1 {        
    a:PreferencesData;
    private state: { preferences: PreferencesData } = {
        preferences: ""
    }
}
```

Why? Because the `:` inside of the object literal separates key/value pairs, so the expression on the right is expected to be the value, not a type annotation.

This does look messy, so you may decide to create an interface for the state object that you have:

```
interface State {
    preferences: PreferencesData;
}

class Example2 {        
    a:PreferencesData;
    private state: State = {
        preferences: ""
    }
}
```

Note: the `""` empty strings above would need to be replaced with a valid `PreferencesData` compatible structure - but the original question doesn't specify what that would be.

Comment: yes. I see now. But would be nice if it was a bit smarter. thx